# linear transformation and surjective function

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations

Good night, i have an big dude with this
 How i can know if an linear transformation is surjective? because for example i know if an function is injective if kernel is 0 but with the surjective function?

Please i need an example of this for understand thanks

I know this:

$f:\,X\,\rightarrow Y$

$\forall y\in Y\:\exists x\:\in X,\:f(x)=y$ is an definition of surjective function.

Comment: it is surjective if its image is equal to the domain it is mapping to

Answer (score 0):

An example of such a linear transformation is: $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$
, $f(x,y) = x+y$.This function is surjective because for every $r \in \mathbb{R}$, take $x = 3, y = r-3$ ,and $f(3,r-3) = r$.

Another exotic example would be $f: \mathbb{P_n} \to \mathbb{P_{n-1}}$, $f(p(x)) = p'(x)$. In this example, $\mathbb{P_n} = \{p(x): p(x) \text{ is a polynomial of degree n } \}$

Answer (score 0):

A linear transformation $T : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is surjective if and only if $\dim(Im(T))=m$.

By the rank -nullity Theorem
$$\dim(Im(T))+\dim(Ker(T))=n$$

Combining these, all you need is to check if 
$$\dim(Ker(T))+m=n$$